# How can I find the meter value in this bitmap image of a gauge

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick

I have just learned Python and have managed to create a script running on a Raspberry Pi that take pictures using an connected USB camera.

Here is a sample image:

[image]

Now I need to detect the value of the meter? Any idea how I should do this. All I can think of are pretty dumb algorithms.

A multi-step ImageMagick procedure maybe? B/W, remove noise, Try to isolate the meter from the background somehow???

Any help is appreciated, but if you have Python code I'm doubly grateful!

I have this idea:

- Create a template image by removing the meter using Photoshop, leaving just the circle with the values
- using ImageMagic, subtract the "new" image from the template
- somehow interpret the resulting diff image?

Comment: Have you looked at [openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html)?

Comment: Yes a little, but it's a huge library! And I'm not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: Always this exact same meter? Or any general meter you happen to come across?

Comment: Yes in this case always the same meter. However I might adapte the code to others later if it is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the arrow from your image using Imagemagick's -connected-components that needs Imagemagick 6.8.9.10 or higher. I believe OpenCV also has something similar.

See http://magick.imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php

We first convert the image to grayscale and then threshold to get the whole arrow with as little else black as possible. Then we use connected components with an area threshold such that the smallest black region is the arrow and use its ID (=42) to extract just that image.

The following in in Unix syntax run on my Mac OSX Sierra with Imagemagick 6.9.10.8 Q16.

Here is one way, assuming you have run this once to get the id and be sure that the arrow item is the last black item (second largest black item in this case).

```
convert image.png -colorspace gray -threshold 45% -type bilevel +write tmp.gif \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:keep=42 \
-connected-components 4 \
arrow.png
```

I have added +write tmp.gif to show the grayscale thresholded image:

[image]

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  5: 94x94+5+7 51.7,53.5 6711 gray(255)
  1: 104x104+0+2 41.6,66.0 2157 gray(0)
  0: 104x54+0+0 50.1,11.3 1412 gray(255)
  175: 37x42+67+64 92.7,94.1 536 gray(255)
  42: 16x49+45+23 51.2,53.6 208 gray(0)
```

Here is the final result:

[image]

Alternately, we can make the area threshold the same and find the ID of the last item in the list and then extract that region in the image.
As above we are extracting the region with the smaller area, which is ID=42 without knowing it is 42.

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert image.png -colorspace gray -threshold 45% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | tail -n +2 | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`)
IFS=$OLD_IFS
num=${#arr[*]}
last_id=`echo "${arr[$num-1]}" | cut -d: -f1`
convert image.png -colorspace gray -threshold 45% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:keep=$last_id \
-connected-components 4 \
arrow2.png
```

[image]

I do not know any good way to automate getting the required area threshold, which should be the number of black pixels in the arrow. But you can, in this case, assume that it would be the second largest area. Thus we can remove the area threshold line and just find it by way of it is the second object with color gray(0):

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert image.png -colorspace gray -threshold 45% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | tail -n +2 | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`)
IFS=$OLD_IFS
num=${#arr[*]}
k=1
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
color=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f5`
id=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f1 | sed 's/[:]*$//'`
echo "k=$k; color=$color; id=$id;"
if [ $k -eq 2 -a "$color" = "gray(0)" ]; then
break;
elif [ "$color" = "gray(0)" ]; then
k=$((k+1))
fi
done
convert image.png -colorspace gray -threshold 45% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:keep=$id \
-connected-components 4 \
arrow3.png
```

[image]

At this point, you could convert that image into polar coordinates and locate the angle of the point. For example:

```
convert arrow.png -virtual-pixel white +distort depolar 0 depolar.png
```

[image]

See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polar

Looking at the checkerboard example, that the output goes from -180 on the left to +180 on the right. The center of the input image is stitch all along the top of the output image. I believer that the zero angle is downward from the center. Clockwise from downward goes from 0 to -180 at the top. Counterclockwise from downward goes from 0 to +180 at the top.

Comment: Great answer, that will take me the better part of a day to digest! One thing: did you run the first command (producing arrow.png) on the sample image I provided? Because when I do the same I get just a black image, and of course the "depolar" doesnt work after that.

Comment: I started with the image that was uploaded to stackoverflow. But they change format often, so it may not be exactly the same image. You could post a link to your image posted to some free image hosting service and I could try again. Also what version of Imagemagick did you use and what platform. My script is in Unix bash code. I ran it with Imagemagick 6.9.10.8 Q16 on my Mac OSX Sierra. Try removing all the end of line \ and make the command into one long line. Also you must have a version of Imagemagick that supports -connected-components (6.8.9.10 or higher).

Comment: See my edits to the answer above. I added the thresholded image. Try `convert image.png -colorspace gray -threshold 45% -type bilevel  tmp.gif`. Do you get the same thresholded result?

Comment: Using Linux Mint and "imagemagick is already the newest version (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12)". WIll investigate whether I can update it in some other way.

Comment: Note that Linux systems do not always upgrade the Imagemagick version with each patch. The date associated with the patch is more important than the version number. There is no such version as 6.8.9.9-7. It would be either 6.8.9.9 or 6.8.9-7. So I am not sure what version of Imagemagick 6 you had on your system. But glad the update to IM 7 worked fine.